# Assign function to multiple elements in one statement in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple inputs and single function for @keyup event:

```
<template>
  <div class="box"> 
    <input v-model="metaData.description" @keyup="changeElement(id)"/>
    <input v-model="metaData.sortOrder" @keyup="changeElement(id)"/>
    <input v-model="metaData.cols" @keyup="changeElement(id)"/>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: "ModelAuto",
  props: ["id", "nodes", "type"],
  data: function() {
    return {
      metaData: {
        description: "",
        cols: 2,
        sortOrder: 0
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeElement: function(id) {
      this.$root.$emit("changeElementEvent", id, this.metaData);
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to assign function *changeElement* to all inputs in one place (in one line of code instead of adding *@keyup="changeElement(id)"* to each input in template)? Something like

```
$('input').keyup(changeElement(id))
```

Comment: you can assign ref to each input and the in script you can addEventListener on each of the refs

Comment: @RajkumarG thanks. But is it possible to assign method for all inputs without assigning ref to each control? Just by type of control (input) or by class. Like in JQuery

Comment: I think the idea here is to explicitly declare what handler to call on an event for a specific element. So that there are no unknown behavior in the application. Consider this if you have 20 inputs on a page and you have applied keyup event handler to all even those on which you don't need, then on every event of key up the handler will be called 20 times even unnecessarily.